# How to display values from a VARIANT with a SAFEARRAY of BSTRs

Tags: delphi, c++builder, bstr, safearray

I am working on a COM Object library with function that returns a `VARIANT` with a `SAFEARRAY` of `BSTR`s. How can I display the values from this `VARIANT` instance and save it inside a `TStringList`? I tried searching the net with no clear answer.

I tried the following with no success:

```
Variant V;
String mystr;

VarClear(V);
TVarData(V).VType = varOleStr;
V = ComFunction->GetValues();  //<<<<----- V is empty
mystr = (wchar_t *)(TVarData(V).VString);
Memo1->Lines->Add(mystr);
VarClear(V);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TWideStringDynArray` and let Delphi do the conversion:

```
procedure LoadStringsFromVariant(const Values: TWideStringDynArray; Strings: TStrings);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Strings.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := Low(Values) to High(Values) do
      Strings.Add(Values[I]);
  finally
    Strings.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

When you call this with your Variant safearray of BSTRs it will be converted to `TWideStringDynArray` automatically. An incompatible Variant will cause the runtime error `EVariantInvalidArgError`.

To check if a Variant holds a safe array of BSTR you can do this:

```
IsOK := VarIsArray(V) and (VarArrayDimCount(V) = 1) and (VarType(V) and varTypeMask = varOleStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
uses ActiveX;

var
  VSafeArray: PSafeArray;
  LBound, UBound, I: LongInt;
  W: WideString;
begin
  VSafeArray := ComFunction.GetValues();
  SafeArrayGetLBound(VSafeArray, 1, LBound);
  SafeArrayGetUBound(VSafeArray, 1, UBound);
  for I := LBound to UBound do
  begin
    SafeArrayGetElement(VSafeArray, I, W);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(W);
  end;
  SafeArrayDestroy(VSafeArray); // cleanup PSafeArray
```

if you are creating `ComFunction` via late binding (`CreateOleObject`) you should use:

```
var
  v: Variant;
v := ComFunction.GetValues;
for i := VarArrayLowBound(v, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(v, 1) do
begin 
  W := VarArrayGet(v, [i]);
  Memo1.Lines.Add (W);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

> **How can I display the values from this VARIANT instance and save it inside a TStringList?**

The COM `VARIANT` struct has `parray` and `pparray` data members that are pointers to a `SAFEARRAY`, eg:

```cpp
VARIANT V;
LPSAFEARRAY sa = V_ISBYREF(&V) ? V_ARRAYREF(&V) : V_ARRAY(&V);
```

The VCL `Variant` class, on the other hand, has an `LPSAFEARRAY` conversion operator defined, so you can assign it directly (but only if the `Variant.VType` field that not have the `varByRef` flag present, that is), eg:

```cpp
Variant V;
LPSAFEARRAY sa = V;
```

Either way, once you have the `SAFEARRAY` pointer, use the SafeArray API to access the `BSTR` values, eg:

```cpp
bool __fastcall VariantToStrings(const Variant &V, TStrings *List)
{
    // make sure the Variant is holding an array
    if (!V_ISARRAY(&V)) return false;

    // get the array pointer
    LPSAFEARRAY sa = V_ISBYREF(&V) ? V_ARRAYREF(&V) : V_ARRAY(&V);

    // make sure the array is holding BSTR values
    VARTYPE vt;
    if (FAILED(SafeArrayGetVartype(sa, &vt))) return false;
    if (vt != VT_BSTR) return false;

    // make sure the array has only 1 dimension
    if (SafeArrayGetDim(sa) != 1) return false;

    // get the bounds of the array's sole dimension
    LONG lBound = -1, uBound = -1;
    if (FAILED(SafeArrayGetLBound(sa, 0, &lBound))) return false;
    if (FAILED(SafeArrayGetUBound(sa, 0, &uBound))) return false;

    if ((lBound > -1) && (uBound > -1))
    {
        // access the raw data of the array
        BSTR *values = NULL;
        if (FAILED(SafeArrayAccessData(sa, (void**)&values))) return false;
        try
        {
            List->BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                // loop through the array adding the elements to the list
                for (LONG idx = lBound; l <= uBound; ++idx)
                {
                    String s;
                    if (values[idx] != NULL)
                        s = String(values[idx], SysStringLen(values[idx]));
                    List->Add(s);
                }
            }
            __finally
            {
                List->EndUpdate();
            }
        }
        __finally
        {
            // unaccess the raw data of the array
            SafeArrayUnaccessData(sa);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

> **VarClear(V);
>   TVarData(V).VType = varOleStr;**

You don't need those at all. The VCL `Variant` class initializes itself to a blank state, and there is no need to assign the `VType` since you are assigning a new value to the entire `Variant` immediately afterwards.

> **V = ComFunction->GetValues(); //<<<<----- V is empty**

If V is empty, then `GetValues()` is returning an empty `Variant` to begin with.

> **mystr = (wchar_t *)(TVarData(V).VString);**

`TVarData::VString` is an `AnsiString&` reference, not a `wchar_t*` pointer. To convert a VCL `Variant` (not a COM `VARIANT`) to a `String`, just assign it as-is and let the RTL works out the detail for you:

```cpp
String mystr = V;
```